# Wcf service metadata is inaccessible because of wrong class name

Tags: wcf, system, metadata

Currently I write a WCF service. The service returns an object whose type is of a user-defined class named "System". The code snippet is as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class System
{
   // ....
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface DemoServcie
{
    [OperationContract]
    System GetSystem();
}
```

But I encoutered a problem when running the wcf service. The error message is:

> Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.
>
> c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client Projects\10.0\6909a900-97bd-4efb-aae9-6c2e9b23e4b9\Client.cs(321,50) : error CS0426: The type name 'Runtime' does not exist in the type 'Demo.DomainModel.System'
>   c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client Projects\10.0\6909a900-97bd-4efb-aae9-6c2e9b23e4b9\Client.cs(264,18) : error CS0426: The type name 'Runtime' does not exist in the type 'Demo.DomainModel.System'
>   ...

But if I rename the class name "System" to other names such as "System1", it is OK. I guess that the "System" is a reserved namespace name and cannot be used. Is it true?

Comment: Seeing as how a large number of the assemblies in the .NET framework start with System, I'd say even if it's not a reserved namespace, using it would be confusing to other developers, at least.

Comment: On a second look, the error is actually that the type `Runtime` does not exist in the type `Demo.DomainModel.System`.  Take a look at line 264 in Client.cs.

Comment: Yes. The "System" name is confusing but it is specified by customer.

Comment: I have looked at the code in the Client.cs. The line where error occurs is just something like "public partial class System : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject".

Comment: If the framework will not allow you to use "System", then you and the customer will have to come up with a different solution/name.

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization in your service project, and do you have a using statement in the code for the assembly?

Comment: Yes. The code can be compiled but just fail to run. You are right that we have to rename the class name.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the line:

```
public partial class System : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{ ... }
```

The problem is that the compiler looks for the Runtime type in the System class you just defined, not in the System Namespace.

If you put global: in front of the System.Runtime, it will at least compile.

```
public partial class System : object, global:System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{ ... }
```

Have a look at the following which illustrates your exact problem with a System class: [How to: Use the Global Namespace Alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 for posting an answer that looks credible without having a whole lot of code to look at :)  Although you might want to edit your answer to put global: in front of System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject in your second code example...

Comment: Oh, yes. This is the cause of the problem. But the file "ClientCode.cs" is auto-generated and we cannot modify it. right?

Comment: You don't have to use the auto generated code. Check the following article: http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/39837/0/page/5 which shows how to manually create your own client proxies.